# Listing all databases in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

I have a basic question about PostgreSQL:
When connecting to my database server via pgadmin3, I can see that there are multiple databases. 
For example, let's say I can see "test", "test1", and "postgres".

From there, I can choose which database I want to connect to.

However, from the command line, I'm doing the following to connect:

```
psql -U adminusername
```

This brings me to a `postgres=#` prompt.

Once connected, I tried to do a `\l` command to see all databases, but the list I get back is different from what I see using pgadmin3.

Just wondering what I might be doing wrong.

Comment: Maybe better suited on serverfault?

Comment: Are you sure you connect to the same DB instance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I list all databases and tables using psql?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you are connecting to *different [database clusters](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/creating-cluster.html)*.
Compare *host* and *port* in your settings in pgAdmin and for psql default connection.

[Read the manual here about connecting with psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html#R2-APP-PSQL-CONNECTING).