# How do I list all databases and tables using psql in a pipable format?

Tags: postgresql, scripting

[This question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql) deals with getting a list. So I get this:

```
$ psql --list
                                    List of databases
      Name      |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges
----------------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 testdb1        | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 odoo           | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 odoo-demo      | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
 odoo8          | openerp  | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 |
```

I could use `psql --list|grep UTF8|awk '{ print $1 }'` to get a list of just the databases. Can `psql` also give me a clean useful list directly?

Comment: The answer is the same, the question title is quite different though. I wouldn't have looked there if I had seen that title.

Comment: Agreed, I've changed the title for something more descriptive. But anyway the `-Atc` switches should be mentioned in the answers of the much more popular question you linked.

Comment: <1k vs >15k views - by now this question has vastly surpassed the other question in popularity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`psql -q -A -t -c "SELECT datname FROM pg_database"` does the trick.