# Display only table names with psql

Tags: postgresql, psql, information-schema

How can I get the table names ***without a header or footer or anything else*** from a specified Postgres database with psql? That is, if I have tables called "table1" and "table2" then the output will be:

```
table1
table2
```

and only that. I've been trying various combinations of things, but it seems like it should be a lot easier than I'm making it.

Comment: better answer here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1285/how-do-i-list-all-databases-and-tables-using-psql

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In PostgreSQL (as described in documentation, [The Information Schema](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/infoschema-tables.html)):

```
SELECT table_name
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_type='BASE TABLE'
AND table_schema='public';
```

For MySQL you would need `table_schema='dbName'` and for MSSQL remove that condition.

Notice that *"only those tables and views are shown that the current user has access to"*. Also, if you have access to many databases and want to **limit the result to a certain database**, you can achieve that by adding condition `AND table_catalog='yourDatabase'` (in PostgreSQL).

If you'd also like to **get rid of the header** showing row names and footer showing row count, you could either start the psql with command line option `-t` (short for `--tuples-only`) or you can toggle the setting in psql's command line by `\t` (short for `\pset tuples_only`). This could be useful for example when piping output to another command with `\g [ |command ]`.

Comment: Hi Esa, that doesn't do the job. It prints a header saying "table name" and a dashed line and underneath it prints "(2 rows)". I just want the table names.

Comment: This is still the solution. It's just how psql shows the results. If you want to suppress header and footer, you can command `\pset tuples_only` first.

Comment: How it shows the results was exactly my point! That's why I said "and only that" and gave an example of the output. I'm not sure how I could have made my question any clearer. But thanks for your help. If you add in that you need to use 'psql -q' and then run \pset tuples_only before the main query then I'll accept your answer (that was how I figured out to suppress all extra output)

Comment: Now the answer should have everything that was asked and desired.

Comment: an easier way is `\dt`